# Divide by zero in ternary statement in bash on RHEL6 but not RHEL7

Tags: bash, conditional-operator, rhel7, rhel6, dividebyzeroexception

UPDATE:

RHEL7 bash version: 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

RHEL6 bash version: 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Okay, so here's a weird one....

I'm remotely executing a bash script on a large number of RHEL6 and RHEL7 servers. A few lines of the script use ternary notation (to save LOC). On the RHEL7 servers, it works fine. On some RHEL6 servers, it throws a divide by zero error every single time.

For context ternary expressions have the following syntax:

EXPR1 ? EXPR2 : EXPR3

If EXPR1 is true, EXPR2 evaluates, otherwise EXPR3 evaluates.

RHEL7 test (works correctly)

```
> cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
> rpm -qa | grep bash
bash-4.2.46-35.el7_9.x86_64
> D21T=569
> NUM=2
> D21A=$((NUM<3 ? D21T/NUM : 9999))
> echo $D21A
284
> D21A=$((NUM<3 ? D21T/NUM : D21T/(NUM-2)))
> echo $D21A
284
```

RHEL6 test (divide by zero)

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
$ rpm -qa | grep bash
bash-4.1.2-48.el6.x86_64
$ D21T=569
$ NUM=2
$ D21A=$((NUM<3 ? D21T/NUM : 9999))
$ echo $D21A
284
$ D21A=$((NUM<3 ? D21T/NUM : D21T/(NUM-2)))
-bash: NUM<3 ? D21T/NUM : D21T/(NUM-2): division by 0 (error token is ")")
```

I'm completely at a loss why this would occur. I suspect a bug in that version of bash, but I can't find it, or I searching for the wrong thing. In any case, it appears as though EXPR3 is evaluating before EXPR1 is tested, but I can't be sure.

Part of me just wants to walk away and use and if statement, but I'd like to work out what is really going on here!

Regards,

Wayne

- Tried changing variable values and increasing the number of parentheses.

Comment: Or `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug that was fixed between 4.1 and 4.2. I reproduced the error on my Mac running bash 3.x, but not on a Debian running 5.x.

Comment: bash version added at top to be clear, however I did have it in the code blocks.

Comment: `D21A=$(( 0 && (1/0) ))` looks like there was no lazy evaluation in bash4.1

Comment: From my testing, it was fixed sometime between bash v4.2.10 (which gets the error) and v4.2.53 (which doesn't). I don't have anything between those handy to test with.

Comment: I did see the `rpm` output, but just in case there's a difference between the RPM and what's actually running, it's best to get the information from the horse's mouth

Comment: Looking through the change logs I couldn't find any real smoking gun there, however both myself and a work colleague here agree that the bug fixes in bash are very scary. Not what one would expect from software that has been around for over 30 years and should be stable.